# Embedding Google Photos album to HTML

Tags: html, google-photos

I have an images slideshow that is based on a Picasa widget.

A few months ago Picasa stopped working and everything moved to Google Photos & Google Drive.

Iv'e searched the web for a compatible widget that will corporate with Google Photos without any luck.

I'm looking for such (simple) widget that works with Google Photos for showing my images as a slideshow.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I wrote this widget to embed google photos gallery into website. Here is a site to generate code for website.
https://www.publicalbum.org/embedding-google-photos-albums.
It is quite similar as picasa widget. Maybe it will be usefull to solve your prolem.

Comment: It's a nice widget but it lacks the features that I look for, such as auto random slideshow. Is it something you can add maybe?

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I added some features such as lazy image loading and slideshow. Press **P** to play continuously or **R** to random slide show.

Comment: Can I do it in the actual code? To set it for random play by default? also to automatically start playing by default?

Comment: You can modify url in iframe to set auto play. Add param `?playRandom&delay=5`

Comment: Looks good. Any additional features? Can I, for example, set the background color to white or transparent maybe? Any other interesting features available?

Comment: Not now, but I'm writing alternative code to embed gallery with many arguments to set individual options such as colors, previews, sharing and the others. I will write a notify here when it's ready. if you have the idea of a useful function, write here,Thanks.

Comment: Amazing, thank you a lot for this.

Comment: @LiorMagen I added some new features to better config widget. You can set auto-slideshow, shuffle list, set background color and transparency, etc.

Comment: Sounds awesome, I really appreciate it and sure many will use it now.

Comment: I would use this solution if it could display an actual grid-like gallery, rather than specifically a slideshow

Comment: I liked this solution as it served my purpose, however, while checking it on a second computer, I noticed that it inserts ads (only occasionally or in full screen), which is not stated anywhere in the answer and is a bit nefarious.

Comment: @Taylor Have to say I've not seen this myself, but I suppose that doesn't mean it doesn't happen

Comment: Does this still work..?  Can't get it working anymore

Comment: @ElSampsa I have completely redesigned the service.You can try.

Comment: Hi @pavex, great service and nice embedded player! Thanks for that great work! Is your source code Open Source and somewhere on GitHub? I would like to integrate albums in my website and contribute to your service...

Answer (score 1):

If you have some image files, just upload them to a public folder on your Google Drive, copy its folder ID from the address bar (e.g. 0B0Gi4v5omoZUVXhCT2kta1l0ZG8) and paste it into a form at [GDrives](http://gdriv.es/), then choose your own alias (e.g. myimgs) and voila! You can access the images one by one using

> e.g. http://gdriv.es/myimgs/myimage.jpg.

If you want to embed a whole folder on your website (in a frame), you can use one of the following URLs, replacing [folderID] with your own ID:

> 1. gdriv.es/myimgs/
> 2. docs.google.com/folder/d/[folderID]/preview?rm=minimal
> 3. drive.google.com/folderview?id=[folderID]

If you prefer to get the file list in XML or JSON, you can use YQL.

Note: You can use Google+ Photos to host ans embed your images as well.

Comment: This is the way for embedding Google Drive folder in a web site but I'm looking to embed the content of a folder as a sliding show

Answer (score 1):

I was just looking for a way to do this myself and found that the easiest way would be using Google Drive to store the photos instead and then embedding them with HTML as per the instructions here:
https://confluence.biola.edu/display/itservices/How+to+Embed+Images+from+Google+Drive+in+a+Web+Page

It may need some styling or free source code to look like a slideshow (or copy part of the iframe code from YouTube's embed button perhaps?)

Comment: You can extract image from page manualy, with object inspector, directly from google photos, or use some tools such as this https://www.publicalbum.org/blog/embedding-google-photos-image. To build custom gallery is a tedius work, but it is possible how to do it. You need all image urls and insert into some existing gallery component.

Comment: Thanks for the contribution @pavex - I was actually using a Wordpress site at the time so the "existing gallery component" in that case was easy to setup. Hope that helps others.